# How to get an array of objects from an array of key-value pair arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
var arr = 
[
["Id", "0011900000YDtPXAA1"],
["Name", "account 50"],
["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
["Phone", "312-552-4450"],
["Id", "0011900000YDtPbAAL"],
["Name", "account 54"],
["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
["Phone", "312-552-4454"]
]
```

I need each subarray to be an object containing one key-value pair.

```
[
{"Id": "0011900000YDtPXAA1"},
{"Name": "account 50"},
...
]
```

I tried

```
var objArr = new Map(arr);
```

This produces the key value pairs I need, but puts them all in the same object. How can I get an array of smaller objects consisting of one k-v pair each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

### 1. Arrow function

```js
var arr = [
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPXAA1"],
  ["Name", "account 50"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4450"],
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPbAAL"],
  ["Name", "account 54"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4454"]
];

const newArr = arr.map(innerArr => ({[innerArr[0]]: innerArr[1]}));

console.log(newArr);
```

### 2. Not arrow function

```js
var arr = [
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPXAA1"],
  ["Name", "account 50"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4450"],
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPbAAL"],
  ["Name", "account 54"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4454"]
];

const newArr = arr.map(function (innerArr) { return {[innerArr[0]]: innerArr[1]}; });

console.log(newArr);
```

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: You have a syntax error.  `{innerArr[0]: innerArr[1]}` should be `{[innerArr[0]]: innerArr[1]}`.

Comment: I used the arrow function after your edit. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a traditional for loop for this

```js
var arr = [
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPXAA1"],
  ["Name", "account 50"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4450"],
  ["Id", "0011900000YDtPbAAL"],
  ["Name", "account 54"],
  ["OwnerId", "005190000023IPPAA2"],
  ["Industry", "Manufacturing"],
  ["Phone", "312-552-4454"]
];

var arr2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  var sub = {};
  
  sub[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];

  arr2.push(sub);

}

console.log(arr2);
```